# Dropdown com opções dinâmicas em formulário Django

Tags: python, django, formulário, django-templates, django-queryset

Tenho um formulário de despesas que possui um campo para selecionar a categoria, porém preciso que as opções sejam obtidas do banco de dados.

Atualmente esse é meu `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Expense

class ExpenseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = '__all__'
```

No `views.py` consigo criar uma query para retornar as categorias:

```
def get_expense_categories():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(""" select * from units_accountplan;""")

        categories = dictfetchall(cursor)
```

Essa tabela `units_accountplan` tem uma estrutura simples:

id  | category

1 | Gasolina

2 | Energia elétrica

É possível utilizar essa query para preencher as opções do formulário, ou alguma outra forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Esta tabela encontra-se dentro dos modelos de dados do Django ou está fora da aplicação?

Comment: está fora da aplicação, é de outro projeto Django que compartilha o mesmo banco, por isso não consigo acessar diretamente pelo model

Comment: Como é um banco de dados de uma outra aplicação a solução mais adequada seria você criar uma API REST na primeira aplicação disponibilizando os dados da tabela `accountplan`, daí recuperar estes dados direto no HTML via JavaScript (É que estou considerando o fato de um dia estas duas aplicações poderão não estar mais no mesmo SGBD).

Answer (score 2):

Levando em consideração que o Model de `AccountPlan` está definido dentro de uma aplicação sua chamada `units` dentro do mesmo database, você precisaria fazer o seguinte no seu `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Expense
from units.models import AccountPlan

class ExpenseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    accountplan = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=AccountPlan.objects.all(),
        label='Account Plan',
        widget=forms.Select
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Expense
        fields = '__all__'
```

Agora caso a tabela `accountplan` esteja em um database diferente você pode mapear este segundo database utlizando [multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/) e mapear a tabela `accountplan` como um Model Django normal, tomando cuidado de definir `Meta.managed = False` e informar o nome da tabela no model. Por exemplo:

```
class AccountPlan(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    data = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'units_accountplan'
```

Depois disto você pode usar o form da forma que mostrei ali em cima, importando seu novo Model.